# Getting an error: parse error on input ‘Just’

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-platform

```
data Type = Nat | Bool | App Type Type | Var String 
     deriving (Eq, Show)

type Substitution = [(String, Type)]

apply :: Substitution -> Type -> Type
apply s Nat = Nat
apply s Bool = Bool
apply s Var c = case (lookup s c) of 
                Nothing -> (Var c)
                Just v  ->  v
```

But the compilers give me the error "error: parse error on input ‘Just’
"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the full error? My first guess is that this is an spacing issue.

Comment: I can not reproduce the error locally, there is however another error: the fact that you forgot to put brackets around `Var c`.

Comment: Prelude> :l unify.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Unify            ( unify.hs, interpreted )

unify.hs:43:17: error: parse error on input ‘Just’
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: You have a TAB character in the `Nothing` line. Don't mix TABs and spaces. GHC should warn about tabs -- turn on warnings if you did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not reproduce the error locally, so my guess is that you used tabs an spaces, if you however copy paste your code into the editor, it should "work". In that case we however receive another error:

```
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tmp.hs, interpreted )

tmp.hs:7:1: error:
    Equations for ‘apply’ have different numbers of arguments
      tmp.hs:7:1-17
      tmp.hs:(9,1)-(11,29)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

This is due to the fact that you write:

```
apply s Var c = -- ...
```

and Haskell assumes that you here wrote three parameters: `s`, `Var`, and `c`, but the `c` of course belongs to the `Var` data constructor. We can fix this with a pair of brackets. Furthermore you call `lookup` in the wrong way: `lookup` has type [**`lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup), so the first argument is the key (here `c`), and the second argument is the lookup table `s`. So we can fix this with:

```
apply :: Substitution -> Type -> Type
apply s Nat = Nat
apply s Bool = Bool
apply s (Var c) = case (lookup c s) of 
    Nothing -> (Var c)
    Just v  ->  v
```

Note that you can get rid of the `case` pattern matching, and use for instance [**`fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) instead:

```
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

apply :: Substitution -> Type -> Type
apply s Nat = Nat
apply s Bool = Bool
apply s d@(Var c) = fromMaybe d (lookup c s)
```

We can furthermore group the `Nat` and `Bool`  case together:

```
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

apply :: Substitution -> Type -> Type
apply s d@(Var c) = fromMaybe d (lookup c s)
apply s t = t
```

This given of course that in case the `Type` is *not* a `Var c` pattern, we should return that `Type`.

Perhaps you need to call `apply` recursively as well, since the substitution can result into another `Var` (and thus you have to do extra lookups). This will however *change the function semantically* (!), so I am not sure if that is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I got an error about the number of args to apply and about the types in lookup, but this code typechecks:

```
data Type = Nat | Bool | App Type Type | Var String
    deriving (Eq, Show)

type Substitution = [(String, Type)]

apply :: Substitution -> Type -> Type
apply s Nat = Nat
apply s Bool = Bool
apply s (Var c) = case (lookup c s) of
    Nothing -> (Var c)
    Just v -> v
```

Note the parentheses around `Var c` and the order of `lookup c s`